# Dynamic GroupBy Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, telerik

I am populating about 10 comboboxes by grouping the data in my database by the column name. So the combobox can be used to filter content.

Heres my function

```
private void SetFilterDataSource(RadComboBox comboBox, string columnName)
{
    var query = (from p in productContext.Products
                       where p.ProductRange != ""
                        group p by p.ProductRange into pGroup
                       select new
                       {
                           ProductRange = pGroup.Key
                       });

    comboBox.DataSource = query;
    comboBox.DataBind();
}
```

At present this would be repeated 10 times for each combobox. So i was wondering if there was a way to make this dynamic based on a string that was passed to it?

Comment: what is the use of columnName? how you want to make dynamic is it based on product range string?

Comment: at the minute nothing but i would like to pass the column name through as a string (or whatever it needs to be). For example if i passed thorough 'Product Range' the query would group the product range column in the database. Or if i passed 'MAterial Group' it would group by material group instead etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write extension and create static method that creates dynamic group by many queries on column names and values using lambda expressions.

See the following link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2008/02/07/linq-groupbymany-dynamically.aspx